# Using @ElementCollection in CriteriaQuery (or Querying over the content of an @ElementCollection)

Tags: java, orm, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

```
public enum ReportStatus { 
    SUCCCEED, FAILED;
}

public class Work {
    @ElementCollection
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    List<ReportStatus> reportStatuses;
}
```

Given the following structure, I'd like to perform a query to find all the work filtered by reportStatuses. It works fine with the following hql syntax :

```
public List<Long> queryHQL() {
    final String query = "SELECT w.id FROM Work w JOIN w.reportStatuses s WHERE s in (:rs)";

    final List<ReportStatus> reportStatuses = new ArrayList<ReportStatus>();
    reportStatuses.add(ReportStatus.FAILED);

    return this.entityManager.createQuery(query).setParameter("rs", reportStatuses).getResultList();
}
```

But I'd like to use the criteria API (jpa2), and can't figure out how to do it. Here is my closest try I think :

```
public List<Long> query() {
    final List<ReportStatus> reportStatuses = new ArrayList<ReportStatus>();
    reportStatuses.add(ReportStatus.FAILED);

    final CriteriaBuilder builder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    final CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
    final Root<Work> workModel = criteriaQuery.from(Work.class);

    final ListJoin<Work, ReportStatus> status = workModel.joinList("reportStatuses");

    final Predicate predicate = status.in(reportStatuses);

    criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
    criteriaQuery.select(workModel.<Long> get("id"));

    return this.entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}
```

I've also tried with the hibernate criteria API, but as the jpa2 one I've failed to find the correct the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use following CriteriaQuery syntax for doing the same thing.

```
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

final List<ReportStatus> reportStatuses = new ArrayList<ReportStatus>();
reportStatuses.add(ReportStatus.FAILED);

final CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

final CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
final Root<Work> _work = criteriaQuery.from(Work.class);

/*final ListJoin<Work, ReportStatus> status = _work.joinList("reportStatuses");
final Predicate predicate = status.in(reportStatuses);
criteriaQuery.where(predicate);*/

final Expression<List<ReportStatus>> _status = _work.get(Work_.reportStatuses);
_status.in(reportStatuses);

criteriaQuery.select(_work.get(Work_.id));

List<Long> list =  em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

## UPDATE

> Thanks, but we do not use the
>   generated metamodel. So unfortunately
>   I can't try with your answer. :(

If you don't use Metamodel, just replace `_work.get(Work_.reportStatuses)` with `_work.get("reportStatuses")`. It'll work. :)

Comment: Thanks, but we do not use the generated metamodel. So unfortunately I can't try with your answer. :(

Comment: @Raphaël Brugier Check the UPDATE part.

Answer (score 3):

You can create this HQL.

```
String query = "SELECT w.id FROM Work w, IN(w.reportStatuses) s WHERE s = :rs";
return this.entityManager.createQuery(query).setParameter("rs", ReportStatus.FAILED).getResultList();
```

Comment: I'd like to point that some JPA SQL supporting tools will mark this as an error when you put a `@ElementCollection` in the `in(~)`, DO NOT trust those tools (in that instance) this works flowlessly and quite fast if you index the right fields (This answer actuallt saved me a few hours of work).

Comment: Where did you find this language feature?  I pored all over the web trying to solve this exact problem, and this answer is the only mention of using the IN clause as a pseudo-table that I found.  It worked flawlessly, though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused. The call to `in(..)` returns a predicate but doesn't seem to actually enforce it (it doesn't seem to be integrated into the query—at least for me it returned all members of the root whether or not their collections intersected with `reportStatuses`. The debug log shows the simple query `select distinct work0_.id as id18_ from Work work0_`).

Also, why bother putting reportStatuses in a list if the caller is only interested in those matching one value? How would you do the query w/ just using `ReportStatus.FAILED` instead of constructing a list for it?